# No input file selected using Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm on Windows and i'm trying to work with Laravel Homestead.

Actually I have the problem of "No input file selected" seems like URL it's not correctly.

My real PATH is this:

`C:\Users\Lluis\Projects` Where I have my projects

And `D:\Homestead_Projects` where I want to copy it when make vagrant up.

My `homestead.yaml` file looks like here:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: c:/Users/Lluis/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
 - c:/Users/Lluis/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: d:/Homestead_Projects
      to: c:/Users/Lluis/Projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: c:/Users/Lluis/Projects/puvik/public  

databases:
    - homestead
```

Anyone see the error? Thanks!

**Edit** Now file looks like here

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
 - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/puvik/public    

databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: Did you ssh into the machine and run `composer install` in your project root? Are your local DB credentials correct in the .env file?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem @lesssugar If was a problem of DB will be an error like "DB can't be established"

Comment: Hi @lesssugar I'm trying to solve it but nothing. When I make homestead ssh this is the route has been created: C:/Users/Lluis/Projects but nothing inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder mapping is a little bit off.

Try this:

```
folders:
    - map: c:/Users/Lluis/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/puvik/public
```

Make sure you don't use `.app` anymore Chrome doesn't like it. use `.test`

Comment: I will try it now Joe @joepferguson I see Chrome doesn't like .app I can't test in chrome haha. Ok, this route in my computer doesn't exist: `/home/vagrant/projects` Like I understand `/home` in Windows it's like `c:/Users/Lluis` true? So my route will be `c:/Users/Lluis/Vagrant/projects` and inside the puvik project? I will try it anyway;)

Comment: Actually I have this route in my computer: `C:\Users\Lluis\vagrant\projects` and inside the project called 'puvik'. `homestead.yaml` looks like yours and same, I make `homestead provision` enter with SSH and only can see folder called `projects` empty. Maybe I make something wrong? @joepferguson

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer You only map your Host OS (Windows) path in the folders, you map that Windows Path to a Linux Path (in the VM) So the site you point to the Linux path of the project you want.

Comment: I understand. I change the file and now the project appears but when I go to homestead.test "No input file selected" But when I do homestead ssh I see the project. I will edit the question and you can see my file now and maybe why don't show it correctly in webpage

Comment: Ok, solved. I don't know why but when make provision create the folders with lower case so site must be like you say first

Answer (score 0):

On my case I had to do a vagrant provision to reload the VM

```
`vagrant provision`
```